# Include only certain file types when searching in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, search, find, replace

Often when I want to search through my code in Visual Studio, I know the thing I'm looking for is in some C# code. However, as I've used the same variable name in a JavaScript file, I have to wade through all those search results too. This gets even worse when the text I'm looking for is also used in a third-party JavaScript library that we've brought into the project: this can result in hundreds of search results.

To compound things, our designers include HTML mock-ups of the pages in the same project, so I often find I'm hitting loads of search results in there too.

I guess what I really want is to see results in my .cs, .aspx, and .ascx files, but not .js or .htm.

Is there any way to do any of the following:

- Search only in files of a particular type (search only .cs files).
- Search only in files of any of a given set of types (search only .cs, .aspx and .ascx files).
- Search in all file types except a particular type or types (search everything except .js).

I suspect not, in which case is there any crafty way of working around this?

Comment: The last option doesn't seem to be available- the file-type selector is only additive, you can specify what to include, but not what to exclude.

Comment: We can all vote for the feature in Visual Studio here:  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2907413-add-exclude-files-to-the-look-in-options-under Doooooo it!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In the Find in Files dialog (Ctrl+Shift+F), there should be a field called Find Options.  You should be able to enter the extensions of fields you want to search in a field in this dialog:

```
*.cs; *.aspx; *.ascx;
```

Comment: +1 the Find-in-Files dialog saves your recent extension choices, so it is easy to choose what set of extensions you want to search.

Comment: This also works in the replace in files dialog, and replace has a few extra buttons, notably "Skip File," which allows you save even more time.

Answer (score 31):

Instead of `Ctrl + F`, I think it is `Ctrl + Shift + F` which gives you the choice to specify file types, you wish to look into.

Comment: Correct on the Ctrl + shift + F.  It also does a find all, which is nicer because with the find, it stops once it finds something, so you have to babysit it to find everything you want.

Comment: You can do find all with the regular find menu also, it's just hidden under the dropdown to the right of the "find" arrow

Answer (score 9):

[image]

You can choose file types from default or type your own. Regular expressions available for complex search.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to limit file searches is by only choosing certain folder sets.

[image: Setting folder sets for search]

Comment: That's a great option! What might also help is to change "Look in:" to "All open documents" and then open just the documents you want to search.

Comment: Dude! Great option. Been using VS since the dawn of time and never saw that before.

Answer (score 6):

I like to exclude js files by using the following search:
`*.a*;*.cs*;`

Most of the times, I end up searching for stuff in aspx, cs, cshtml files so this is quite helpful.
Notice how I use `*.cs*` instead of `*.c*` since the latter would select jquery custom files such as jquery.custom1234.js (which I usually use in most of my projects), of course if you don't you could just use `*.c*`.

Comment: I found this one to be the best, although it does include .css files, which may not be desirable. I also like to add two more for Web.Config's and Site.Master (if that exists):

Comment: to omit css files:  `*.a*;*.cs;*.csh*;*.Config;*.Master;`

Answer (score 1):

In the Find dialog box, go to "find options->Look at these file types".

Type in you own string, eg, `*.cs, *.aspx, *.ascx`. The click the "find all" button.