# Visual Studio find - filter by file type?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, replace

Is there any way to use Visual Studio's Find and Replace to search only through files of a specified type or types?

If I'm searching through my web project for a particular string, it winds up looking through all my javascript, css and html files when I know all that I'm interested in is results that are in .cs files, for example.

I find myself using Notepad++ which does have the ability to limit its "Find In Files" search to only the file types I specify within the directory I specify, but would love an integrated solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude file types from search in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749837/exclude-file-types-from-search-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I often wonder if anyone even searches first. Googling "Visual Studio search by file type" returned nearly this exact SO question asked over a year ago.

Comment: What is interesting is that if you Google "Visual Studio *find* by file type" there aren't any SO results in the first six pages (except for this new question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Find Options, you can specify the settings under "Look at these file types:"

Comment: Okay, Find In Files as opposed to Quick Find. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

[image: Find options]

You can choose file types from default or type your own. Regular expressions available for complex search.

Comment: You get to this dialog with: Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that we needed the wildcard asterisk.