# search in solution folder in visual studio 2013 for specific pattern in code

Tags: visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2013

So after some extensive searching I am embarrassed to say i cant figure this out. Lets say I have the comment //tebow in an mvc4.5 application. Or I have tebow displaying on the page but i dont know if its in a controller or in static html.

In sublime text i could right click and say "find in this folder" and it would search the text in all the files in that root folder.

How do i do this in visual studio pro 2013? Searching in the solution explorer doesnt seem to do it. For example it couldnt find the string "powerful" in the out of the box mvc example even though i know its on the index.chtml file.

[This didnt really help but its slightly close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749837/exclude-file-types-from-search-in-visual-studio?s=2%7C2.6397)

**update** so i figured out i can do Control Shift F to find. is there a visual way to keep this search somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do Ctrl+Shift+F to search, all of the search results are listed in the "Find Results 1" tool window. To open it, go View - Find Results - Find Results 1, or press Ctrl+Tab and use arrow keys to navigate to it.
Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by "visual way"? :)

Comment: I was just thinking there should be some affordance for a user to know how to search through all of their code. IE i was thinking the "search solution explorer should do it or have some setting" or how sublime has you right click on a folder and search in all folders. Thanks for the help